# How to use cat append one file without deleting the original

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I'm using the following command to merge some files in multiple folders to one.

```
$dir=`ls`; for d in $dir; do files=`ls $d`; for f in $files; do cat $d/$f>>../results/$f; done; done
```

But after doing that, the original one is missing, how can I do that without deleting the old one.

Thanks.

Comment: Just move it somewhere if it already exists? `[ -f "../results/$f" ]` to check existence.

Comment: @hidefromkgb, there are some concatenate work if multiple files shared the same name.

Comment: @chepner ../results, d will not equal result.

Comment: @chepner yeah, `results` is 1 level above where we stand and look for dirs.

Comment: @hidefromkgb, but cat will delete the original file, how to avoid this?

Comment: you could just move all files away from `results` before the loop begins.

Comment: @hidefromkgb I could, but it's not elegant, considering all the files are quite large, cp will take another hour to finish, any other option to finish them in one step?

Comment: @hidefromkgb results folder is empty, I want to keep original dir file not delete, btw.

Comment: okay, wait a sec, I\`ll sketch something in the answer section.

Comment: @PythonNewHand: I'm not clear on what "original" file is getting deleted. Is it the ones found as `$d/$f`? If so, `cat` will not delete them, so there has to be something else going on. Also, when you say "deleted", do you mean the file is completely gone, or still there but empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still unsure if I get your point correctly, but anyway, here`s the code:

```
$dir=`ls`
$res=$(ls ../results)
for d in $dir; do
    files=`ls $d`
    for f in $files; do
        grep -q "$f" "$res" && f="${f}1"
        cat $d/$f>>../results/$f
    done
done
```